# How can I prove that $Aut(C_p\times C_p)\simeq GL_2(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How can I prove that $Aut(C_p\times C_p)\simeq GL_2(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$?

No theorical argument came to my mind, so I'm trying to build explicitly an isomorphism $\phi:Aut(C_p\times C_p)\longrightarrow GL_2(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$, but I'm stuck.

Can someone help me please? Thank you all

Comment: You know that $C_p\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Then given a $\phi$, look here $\phi$ takes $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. If you know this can you build a matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$? Do these matrices classify all the automorphism?

Comment: All clear, thank you!

Comment: The point is that an automorphism of $C_p \times C_p$ as an abelian group is automatically an automorphism of it as an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space, or said another way, having an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space structure is in fact a property rather than a structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $G=C_p \times C_p$ in addition, you will find each element of $G$ is a linear combination of $a,b$ with coefficient in $F_p$, where $a, b$ are the generators of $G$. Then you can check that a hommormorphism of $G$ (in multiplication) will become linear transformation (in addition). Then you can get your proof.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint.* Define $\pi_1:(x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$ and $\pi_2:(x,y)\mapsto (0,y)$.  Show that an automorphism $\phi:C_p\times C_p\rightarrow C_p\times C_p$ is completely determined by $\pi_1\phi\pi_1$, $\pi_2\phi\pi_1$, $\pi_1\phi\pi_2$, and $\pi_2\phi\pi_2$.  Then prove that there is an isomorphism between $\operatorname{Aut}(C_p\times C_p)$ and $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ using this information.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $C_p \cong \mathbb{Z}/ p \mathbb{Z}$ is  vector space

Comment: Over what field? Isn't $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ a field itself?

Comment: @chs21259: it's a vector space over itself, i.e. of dimension $1$

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks for clarifying