# How to prove that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/p )\simeq GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Anyone can give me any clue about the proof of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p \times\cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/p )\simeq GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p)$? Thank you.

Comment: Show any automorphism is a vector-space isomorphism over $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ (which is very easy), and you are done.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805590 for the case $n=2$

Answer (score 4):

If $A,B$ are abelian groups with $pA=pB=0$, then $A,B$ are $\mathbb{Z}/p$-vector spaces in a unique way. Besides, a homomorphisms $A \to B$ of abelian groups is already $\mathbb{Z}/p$-linear (since it is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear and $\mathbb{Z}$ maps onto $\mathbb{Z}/p$). It follows in particular that automorphisms of $A$ as an abelian group coincide with automorphisms of $A$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/p$-vector space.